# how to log a indentation error in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, error-handling, try-except

Hi i'm trying to log indentation error in function test().but when i run the code it's executing without any error. can anyone please tell me the reason here.

```
def test():
        try:                        //1
                        print "ABC" //2//indentaton error//
                logger.info("printed")//3
        #except Exception as e://
                #logger.error("Exception occured while order dictionary",exc_info=True)
        except IndentationError as e://4
                logger.error("indentation err",exc_info=True)//5
```

Answer (score 1):

Python parses the entire code file *before* it begins to execute any code. Unfortunately `IndentationError` is a subclass of `SyntaxError`, which is an error that can only be caught from `eval`, `exec`, or `import` statements.

For the purposes of your test, you can write some broken code into a separate file and try to import that file as a module. That way you can catch the `IndentationError`, if that's relevant to you.

Comment: i have one running code where some indentation changes happened & code was not giving desired output. After spending some time i came to realize it's due to indentation only. I have logger applied in the code but it doesnt log any error.

Comment: Yes, that's what the answer says. You cannot use logging inside the file that has wrong indentation, because the wrong indentation is a problem **before any code in that file can run**. You must use some other means for logging. But you do not need or want logging here, because **the error message already tells you** where the problem is. Logging is for understanding problems that happened because of input to the program. It is not for finding syntax problems.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Python to be comprehending code in levels, where indentations define what level each code is a part of.

As a result, it is possible to go from Level 2 (try statement - line 2) to Level 4 (line 3) just like you can go from Level 2 to Level 3 normally.

However, if you try to go from Level 2 to Level 1 without the try statement being compiled as per its defined syntax, you shall receive an error.

Instead of doing the above to catch indentation errors like above, perhaps, try defining a function that checks for levels instead of errors being thrown by Python compiler.

Just to provide a bit of clarification, here's your code with level and line numbers printed:

```
1    def test():                                           //Level 1
2            try:                                          //Level 2
3                            print "ABC" //indentaton error//Level 4
4                    logger.info("printed")                //Level 3
5            #except Exception as e:
6                    #logger.error("Exception occured while order dictionary",exc_info=True)
7            except IndentationError as e:                 //Level 2
8                    logger.error("indentation err",exc_info=True)//Level 3
```

Let me know if you have any other queries.

Comment: can you please explain in reference with line no. i'm bit confused with your levels numbering. i have edited the code with line numbers.

Comment: Sure, I just added in a bit of clarification with level and line numbers. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As [alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53809193/7050515) told, we can follow the same, a one of the workign method is that one.
However to catch the syntax error, import the try2.py as module in another file.

try1.py and try2.py are python files  respectively.

```
# try2.py
try:
   import try1
except IndentationError as in_ex:
   print in_ex

#try1.py
def test():
    try:                        
             print "ABC" //2//indentaton error
             logger.info("printed")//3
    #except Exception as e://
            #logger.error("Exception occured while order 
              dictionary",exc_info=True)
    except IndentationError as e://4
            logger.error("indentation err",exc_info=True)//5
```

Comment: what is try1 & try2